# SymmetricDS Multi-Tier Configuration

Tags: symmetricds

I have host A and guest B. Node B also can be a host of guest C. So the tier is A - B - C.

At host A, I set sync.url is IP of PC A. At host B, I set sync.url is IP of PC B and register.url is IP of PC A. At host C, I set register.url is IP of PC B.

Is that correct with that properties configuration?

And also I'm using MySQL, because of node B is a host and a guest, it needs 2 trigger. But, MySQL can only use 1 trigger. How?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, that's correct. no need for two triggers. one is enough. then have two routers. for example, at the node B have one router sending data to the node A and another that will send data to node C

Comment: but at node C, it cannot register sym_node_identity on itself because this node is not registered yet

Comment: failed sql was: insert 'into sym_node_identity' ('node_id') values (?)

Comment: wait for the node B to register with node A then node C will register with node B. symmetricds SQL configuration should be inserted only at node A. upon registration B will receive it and propagate it to C upon its registration

Comment: Send data from A to B and declare the trigger on B with `sync_on_incoming_batch = 1` as explained here: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_bi_directional_synchronization